# Create a node dynamically in c++

Tags: c++, database

I want to make a database engine in `C++`. For that I need to make a `class` dynamically and store it within a file. My approach to this project is that when the user enters the name of a new database, a `text` file is created with that name. However, for search functions and retrieving the data I need to store it in a node and the node needs to have a the entities of the database as partitions within the data block of the node. I've looked everywhere but apparently no `class` can be made at `run-time`. Can this be done instead? Have a pre-declared node class and adding entities to it.

Comment: The approach seems wrong. The on-disk representation of the database should not be tied to a particular program translation. Rather, you should have a well-specified, public serialization format and implement against that.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for name-value pairs -- try to look at `stl::map` as one way of implementing that.